# Is this a bug of TThread under android?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

on windows, we can call several time MyThread.waitfor on the same thread. if the thread is already terminated no problem this will not raise any exception and return immediatly (normal behavior).

on Android, it's different, if we call twice MyThread.waitfor then we will have an exception on the second try with "No such process".

```
function TThread.WaitFor: LongWord;
{$ELSEIF Defined(POSIX)}
var
  X: Pointer;
  ID: pthread_t;
begin
  if FExternalThread then
    raise EThread.CreateRes(@SThreadExternalWait);
  ID := pthread_t(FThreadID);
  if CurrentThread.ThreadID = MainThreadID then
    while not FFinished do
      CheckSynchronize(1000);
  FThreadID := 0;
  X := @Result;
  CheckThreadError(pthread_join(ID, X));
end;
{$ENDIF POSIX}
```

the error is made because on call to waitfor they set FThreadID := 0 so off course any further call will failled

i think it's must be written like :

```
function TThread.WaitFor: LongWord;
{$ELSEIF Defined(POSIX)}
begin
  if FThreadID = 0 then exit;
  ...
end;
{$ENDIF POSIX}
```

what do you think ? did i need to open a bug request at emb ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [`pthread_join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) says:

> Joining with a thread that has previously been joined results in undefined behavior.

This explains why `TThread` takes steps to avoid invoking undefined behavior.

Is there defect in the design? That's debatable. If we are going to consider the design of this class, let's broaden the discussion, as the designers must. A Windows thread can be waited on by multiple different threads. That's not the case for pthreads. The linked documentation also says:

> If multiple threads simultaneously try to join with the same thread, the results are undefined.

So I don't think Embarcadero could reasonably implement the same behaviour on Posix platforms as already exists on Windows. For sure they could special case repeated waits from the same thread, as you describe. Well, they'd have to persist the thread return value so that `WaitFor` could return it. But that would only get you part way there, and wouldn't be very useful anyway. After all, why would you wait again from the same thread?

I suspect that `FThreadID` is set to 0 in an effort to avoid the undefined behaviour and fail in a more robust way. However, if multiple threads call `WaitFor` then there is a data race so undefined behaviour is still possible.

If we were trying to be charitable then we could

Leaving those specific details to one side, it is clear that if `WaitFor` is implemented by calling `pthread_join` then differing behaviour across platforms is inevitable. Embarcadero have tried to align the `TThread` implementations for each platform, but they cannot be perfectly equivalent because the platform functionality differs. Windows offers a richer set of threading primitives than pthreads.

If Embarcadero had chosen a different path they could have aligned the platforms perfectly but would have needed to work much harder on Posix. It is possible to replicate the Windows behaviour there, but this particular method would have to be implemented with something other than `pthread_join`.

Facing the reality though, I think you will have to adapt to the different functionality of pthreads. In pthreads the ability to wait on a thread is included merely as a convenience. You would do better to wait on an event or a condition variable instead, if you really do want to support repeated waits. On the other hand you might just re-create your code to ensure you only wait once.

So, to summarise, you should probably raise an issue with Embarcadero, if there isn't one already. It is possible that they might consider supporting your scenario. And it's worth having an issue in the system. But don't be surprised if they choose to do nothing and justify that because of the wider platform differences that cannot be surmounted, and the extra complexity needed in the class to support your somewhat pointless use case. One thing I expect we can all agree on though is that the Delphi documentation for `TThread.WaitFor` should cover these issues.

Comment: thanks david, but if you look the implementation of waitfor, they set FThreadID := 0 so any further call to waitfor can check if FThreadID = 0 and if yes return immediatly ?

Comment: They could do that I suppose. But they couldn't have multiple threads waiting. Why are you waiting twice from the same thread anyway.

Comment: it's not really about multiple thread but multiple function .. for exemple when you have several function (that are all called from the main thread) that need to wait that the thread is finished before to continue (these function are all standalone). so all of then make a quite test MyThread.waitfor. of course i can update all function by if not MyThread.checkTerminated then MyThread.waitfor

Comment: In this case, don't wait on the thread itself. Create a separate `TEvent` and wait on that instead, and have the thread signal the event when finished.  This will also allow you to migrate your code to use a thread pool in the future, if needed, without having to change the wait code again.

Comment: @loki But the designers of the class have to care about more than your scenario

Comment: "Undefined' means *undefined*.  i.e Since FireMonkey is supposed to provide an abstraction across different platforms, where consistent behaviour is possible and does not otherwise conflict with **defined** behaviour then there is no reason to *not* be consistent.  In this case, consecutive waits in thread A on B *could* be consistent.  Waits in *multiple* threads on the same thread is not able to be consistent (but is still undefined, so can be inconsistent in any way you like).  It also doesn't alter the fact that there may be better ways to do what the OP is after (as per Remy's comment).

Comment: @remy: yes off course i have solution to avoid this problem, but here the question was simply: is it not better to just add in waitfor if FThreadID = 0 then exit; to make that waitfor have the same behavior on windows and android ? i agree with Deltics

Comment: No. WaitFor needs to return a value. So it would have to remember that also.

Comment: @Deltics They could have chosen to have perfect consistency across platforms. It would have required more effort though. The method under consideration here, for example, would have needed to be implemented with something other than pthread_join.